# psycopg2 could not truncate postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a python code which tries to truncate a postgres table. Here is the method which does that :

```
def truncate(self, tablename):
        curs = self.conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE %s" % tablename)
        curs.close()
        self.conn.commit()
        return
```

Why does program flow get stuck when it reaches this method? By stuck I mean control enter into this method but does not come out or throw exception. It just get halted.

Comment: What does "halted" mean? How long are we talking?

Comment: Semantically, I can't see anything wrong with your code. It either takes a long time or ... something...

Comment: Is it possible that another process has a lock on the table?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` should be pretty fast.  The fact that it hangs means you are probably blocked by another process/transaction.  You might want to try `psql` and see if `TRUNCATE` still hangs.  If so, check `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity` and see what's blocking you

Comment: I don't think there is any other process with a lock on the table. Program flow stops once it enter this method. I had to manually stop it.

Comment: I tried truncate command from pgadmin and it works. I don't know why it does not from a python program.